# QueryDSL - auto trimming of DB2 varchar fields

Tags: querydsl

I have a Mysema QueryDSL project to maintain... Columns in DB2 and also SQL Server are varchars, the result is that the fields have the length of the columns and not the data.

My Java code is:

```
QTransferTableLeveranciers leveranciers =
     QTransferTableLeveranciers.transferTableLeveranciers;
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(leverancier);
return query.list(leveranciers);
```

How to instruct QueryDSL to trim, leading and trailing spaces of the data?

I have read the SO question, but dont know how to apply it to my code:
[Automatic trimming in QueryDSL with Bean Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092002/automatic-trimming-in-querydsl-with-bean-projection?s=1|0.7099)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the entities via JPA. Querydsl helps only in the maintenance with the queries in your case.

The trailing whitespace issues needs to be fixed at either the database level or in the configuration of your JPA provider.